# How to declare number in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, numbers

In as3 I'd say

```
public var time:Number;
```

How to declare such in C#?

Comment: Reading an intro to c# programming instead of trying to create syntax out of whole cloth might help.  Here's a reference on c# value types : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch(v=VS.80).aspx

Comment: Oh, come on. You should know that given your previous C# questions!

Comment: @norheim.se =) in general - yes but when I see  time:Number i began to feel scared... and thats when I call the community for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the type you want:

```
public double time;
```

or you could use the `DateTime` struct provided by .NET

```
public DateTime time;
```

or really, you would probably want to create auto-properties for these like this:

```
public double Time {get;set;}
```

or

```
public DateTime Time {get;set;}
```

Answer (score 4):

See "[Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173104.aspx)".

You probably want an int, long, float, double, decimal - or maybe DateTime or TimeSpan.

Answer (score 4):

AS3 Number is most closely represented by a double in C#

```
public double time;
```

[Number in AS3](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/Number.html)

[Double in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9(VS.71).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
public long time;
```

This will create a new variable with the type `long` and the default value. (`0`)

Comment: Number in AS3 is a data type representing an IEEE-754 double-precision floating-point number.

Answer (score 1):

`public decimal time;`

decimal depending of course on the type you want.

Answer (score 1):

C# has a a `DateTime` data type, so for dates I would create a variable like this:

```
public DateTime time;
```

This lets you do things like subtract dates, and make use of the [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) structure.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for small integer:

```
public int Number;   // This stores whole numbers. e.g., 3, 9 , -3.
public float Number; // This stores numbers with decimals. e.g., 3.27, -3.45
```